# How to get the url of downloading page in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a Chrome extension and I have two questions:

1. What I want is to get the URL of the page from which my file is getting downloaded.
2. How to restrict the JavaScript to just act on only some of the URLs and not all? I tried it using content_scripts matches but it didn't work. What to do?

Comment: 1. Which file? 2. Which JS? What is "it did not work"?

Comment: any file which I download .I have a javascript wriiten to change the name of file downloaded .But what I want is that the extension should work only on files downloaded by selected URL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename downloads using [`chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onDeterminingFilename).

Use [`downloadItem.referrer`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#type-DownloadItem) to figure out where the download was initiated. This could be an empty string, e.g. when the user typed the download URL in the omnibox.

Here is an example that adds a prefix "downloadprefix-" before every file name if the download originates from `http://www.example.com` or `https://www.example.com/`.

```js
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(downloadItem, suggest) {
    if (/^https?:\/\/www\.example\.com\//.test(downloadItem.referrer)) {
        suggest({
            filename: 'downloadprefix-' + downloadItem.filename
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Where can I get an example on how to use downloaditem.referrer?

Comment: @user3851486 Yes it works. JavaScript is case-sensitive, so use lowercase `d`.